# Query : Group By one column and select antoher column

Tags: sql, oracle

I would have a problem with a query

I should make a query that takes the last state ( so check the date), Grouped for a called column mat_calc.

```
mat_calc | STATE | DATE

1 | NEW | 25/03/2016

1 | DONE |25/01/2016

2 |PROC |25/04/2016

2 |PROC |25/07/2016

2 |DONE |25/09/2016

3 |NEW |25/01/2016

3 |PROC |25/06/2016

3 |DONE |25/02/2016

3 |OK |25/12/2016

4 |OK |25/03/2016
```

So I should give it back :

the mat_cal With its status

```
1 | NEW

2 | DONE

3 | OK

4 | OK
```

My query is

```
select mat_cal AS mat_cal , STATO AS STATO, MAX(DATA) AS DATA
from CALC
group by mat_cal ;
```

It gives me trouble on the group id because it looks like I DO NOT use it.

How can i do it? Thanks

Sorry,i can't do a tables with stack overflow

Comment: Please add Stato in group by ....                                                         group by mat_cal,STATO

Comment: But in this case the query group by Stato too. And this is not good .

For Example.. for mat_calc 2 come out twice : 2 |Done and 2 |PROC

Comment: Whats the error you getting? what u mean by this is not good ?

Comment: ORA-00979: is not a expression GROUP BY
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Answer (score 1):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select c.*
from (select c.*,
             row_number() over (partition by mat_cal order by data desc) as seqnum
      from calc c
     ) c
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: you should change the first row from: "select c.*" to "select c.mat_cal,c.STATO,c.DATA"

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `Group By` clause you need to do it with all the columns selected. If you don't do that you'll get the `ORA-00979` exception.

Try adding the `STATO` column to the `Group By`.

```
   select mat_cal AS mat_cal , STATO AS STATO, MAX(DATA) AS DATA
    from CALC
    group by mat_cal, STATO ;
```

Comment: In this case the query group by Stato too. And this is not good . For Example.. for mat_calc 2 come out twice : 2 |Done and 2 |PROC – Dev 12 mins ago

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following:

```
--creating the data you publishied
 with calc (mat_cal,STATO,date)
 as 
 (
 select '1' as mat_cal,'NEW' as STATO,'25/03/2016' as date
 union
 select '1','DONE','25/01/2016'
 union
 select '2','PROC','25/04/2016'
 union
 select '2','PROC','25/07/2016'
 union 
 select '2','DONE','25/09/2016'
 union 
 select '3','NEW','25/01/2016'
 union 
 select '3','PROC','25/06/2016'
 union 
 select '3','DONE','25/02/2016'
 union 
 select '3','OK','25/12/2016'
 union 
 select '4','OK','25/03/2016')


--the query to solve the problem 
select mat_cal , STATO ,date
from CALC as c
where c.date = (select max(date) from calc as c2 where c.mat_cal = c2.mat_cal group by c2.mat_cal)
```